# Building a parametrised query from a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a query with multiple arg params via a function (as follows):

```
public function insert_(array $args) {
    $errormsg = "";
    if ($args == null) {
        return $errormsg;
    }
    if ($args == array()) {
        return $errormsg;
    }

    $query = "";

    try {
        foreach ($args as $arg) {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception $exec) {

    }
}
```

But the bit that I cannot seem to figure out is how to build the query inside. Do I need to do `$query .= $arg;`? Or something very different to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use sprintf() to build your query? e.g.

```
sprintf($query, $arg);
```

Inside your while loop and then outside use:

```
mysql_query(result_of_sprintf);
```

Comment: I have and it didn't work, because it just overwrote the param in the <code>$query</code> param